# Puzzle: Cut regular tetrahedron into distinct-sized regular tetrahedra?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry, tiling

The classic problem of constructing a [perfect squared square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square), i.e. [tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) a [square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square) with a [finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set) number of squares of pairwise distinct sidelengths (which [must](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14878/cutting-a-unit-square-into-smaller-squares/14920#14920) be rational multiples of the tiled square's, so we need only look for [integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) tilings) has solutions (one is shown below). However, it has been [proved](https://carlo-hamalainen.net/stuff/Tutte%20-%20The%20dissection%20of%20equilateral%20triangles%20into%20equilateral%20triangles%20%281948%29.pdf) impossible to tile an [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) with equilateral triangles of distinct sizes (elegant proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/326691/284973)). It is also impossible to do it for other (more-sided) [regular polygons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_polygon) since the angle between a corner piece and the side of the tiled polygon will be [acute](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_angle).

In [three dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space#In_euclidean_geometry), one can [prove](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square#Cubing_the_cube) very [elegantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) that it is impossible to divide a [cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) into a finite number of cubes of distinct sizes. A natural generalization is to ask whether it is possible to divide a [regular tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron) into tetrahedra of distinct sizes (I assume  the other [Platonic solids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid) will not work)? This problem appears more complicated, and I don't know if either impossibility proof (for cube or equilateral triangle) will generalize to tetrahedra. ([This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1983732/division-of-regular-tetrahedron) appears to be asking something somewhat different, related to a specific type of division).

It *is* [possible](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.5199v2.pdf) however to tile an equilateral triangle with equilateral triangles which can have the same size if their [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientation_(geometry)) is different; an example is shown below. It is worth wondering whether such a dissection might be possible for the tetrahedron.

Thus I have the following **questions**:

1. Is it possible to divide a regular tetrahedron into regular tetrahedra of distinct sizes?
2. If it is possible, can a proof like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14916/284973) be extended to show that all dissections are rational?
3. Is the dissection possible if we only force tetrahedra of the same orientation to have distinct sizes?

---

*Perfect squared square:*

$\hskip2in$[image: Squared square]

*Equilateral triangle dissection:*

$\hskip2in$[image: Triangled triangle]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2714037/tetrahedron-into-similar-tetrahedron

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to dissect a regular tetrahedron into any finite number${}>1$ of regular tetrahedra at all. This is simply because the angle between the faces of a regular tetrahedron, which is the angle that it occupies around any one of its edges, measured in a plane perpendicular to that edge, is $\arccos(\frac13)$ and this is not of the form $\frac{2\pi}n$ for any integer$~n$; therefore one can never complete the remaining angle with a number of regular tetrahedra.

Here is a bit more rigorous argument. Clearly such a decomposition will have an edge $e$ of some smaller tetrahedron$~t$ across a face of the original tetrahedron ("across" meaning lying in the face but not along an edge of it). The plane perpendicular to$~e$ and cutting it at the middle has an angle of$~\pi$ for the interior of the original tetrahedron (the remaining angle$~\pi$ being the exterior). Of this flat angle, $t$ occupies $\arccos(\frac13)$, but $\pi-\arccos(\frac13)$ is not an integer multiple of $\arccos(\frac13)$, and so we cannot fill this remaining angle completely with tetrahedra, so we will fail to cover some points in the neighbourhood of the edge$~e$.

We see that it would actually be necessary to have an angle of the form $\frac\pi n$ rather than the more liberal $\frac{2\pi}n$ to succeed. If you try to arrange regular tetrahedra around a common edge, you will see that you can manage $5$ but that a small angle is left, way to small to fit in a sixth regular tetrahedron.

Comment: I almost see what you're saying... why must $f$ be irrational?

Comment: I rewrote to make the argument more evident. The point is just $\arccos(\frac13)$ is not of the form $\frac\pi n$ with $n$ integer; the fact that it is an irrational multiple of $\pi$ is much stronger, and true, but not needed.

Comment: Nice proof. +1. It's a bit disappointing that the tetrahedron case is so relatively trivial compared to the square, cube and equilateral triangle, but a nice proof regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach, which shows the much stronger statement that a tetrahedron cannot be cut into polyhedral pieces that are then reassembled into smaller regular tetrahedra. We'll do this by proving that any collection of equal-volume smaller tetrahedra don't have the same Dehn invariant as the large one.

Let our large tetrahedron have unit edge length, and let its dihedral angle be $\theta\approx 70.529^\circ$, not a rational multiple of $\pi$. Then the Dehn invariant is $6\cdot (1\otimes \theta) = 6\otimes \theta\neq 0$.

If a collection of smaller tetrahedra have edge lengths $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_n$, then they have Dehn invariants $(6\ell_1\otimes\theta),\ldots,(6\ell_n\otimes\theta)$ so their disjoint union has Dehn invariant $6\sum\ell_i\otimes\theta$.

But since all $\ell_i$ are less than $1$ by assumption and their volumes add to the volume of the original tetrahedron,

$$1 = \sum_{i=1}^n\ell_i^3 < \sum_{i=1}^n\ell_i$$

so the Dehn invariant of the small tetrahedra will exceed that of the large one and they will have a nonzero difference.

(This doesn't rely on the tetrahedron in any particular way except that the Dehn invariant is especially simple - the general theorem here is that a polyhedron is dissection-congruent into a collection of scaled-down copies if and only if it has Dehn invariant $0$, e.g. by being a space-filling polyhedron.)